# About the Normal distribution

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution, sampling, quantiles

I'm having troubles understanding the following problem

**Problem**

The volume of daily transactions (in millions of shares) in the
New York Stock Exchange is a random variable that is distributed
normally with mean 950 and standard deviation 85. It asks for:

**a.** What is the probability that on a given day, the level of
transactions is between 900 and 1000?

**b.** What is the value such that on 80% of the days, the level of transactions is
higher than this value?

**c.** If a random sample of 300 days is taken, what is the probability of
that between 150 and 250 of these days, it is fulfilled that the volume of
transactions is less than 1000?

**What I think**

for **a**

if $X=N(950,85^2)$

then the pdf is

$f\left(x;\:950;\:85^2\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }85}e^{-\frac{1}{2\left(85\right)^2}\left(x-950\right)^2}$

and the probability asked is

$P\left(900<X<1000\right)=\int _{900}^{1000}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }85}e^{-\frac{1}{2\left(85\right)^2}\left(x-950\right)^2}dx$

In R I can compute that as

`pnorm(q=1000, mean=950, sd=85)-pnorm(q=900, mean=950, sd=85)`

The result is $0.4436256$

Now for part b and c is where I'm having troubles.

For **b** the first thing that I thought was finding the following quantile

$\int _a^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }85}e^{-\frac{1}{2\left(85\right)^2}\left(x-950\right)^2}dx=0.8$

which in R is
`qnorm(p=0.8, mean=950, sd=85, lower.tail = F, log.p = F)`

which results in $878.4622$

But I'm noticing that the random variable $X$ measures The volume of daily transactions (in millions of shares), and the problem is asking me for the value such that on 80% of the days, the level of transactions is higher than this value? and I think they aren't the same thing. And I'm stuck there.

For part **c** I'm not sure on how to represent the problem.

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: In question b, you are seeking $a$ such that $\mathbb P(X>a)=0.80$, there is no upper bound (like 1000). The R solution is thus correct. In question c, you have to introduce a Binomial random variable $N$ with $n=300$ and a certain value of $p$ I let you figure out to find $\mathbb P(150\le N\le 250)$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for clarifying I already change the upper bound, and thanks for the hint of using the Binomial random variable $N$, if $n=300$ the value of $p$, given what the exercise ask, would be $p=P(X<1000)$, right?

Comment: @Xi'an in that case $P(X<1000)=0.2781872$ so $N=Binom(300, 0.2781872)$  so $P(150≤N≤250)$ could be  `sum(dbinom(150:250,300, 0.2781872))` which gives me $3.924218e-16$

Comment: @Xi'an Yes! right it's $0.7218128$  so $N=Binom(300,0.7218128)$ and $P(150≤N≤250$ `sum(dbinom(150:250,300, 0.7218128))` = $0.9999979$ right? which is kind of high right? It's not weird?

Comment: Using a Normal approximation to the probability returns $6~10^{-6}$ as the probability to be outside $(150,250)$, so this sounds correct.

Comment: @Xi'an yes, right it did not came to my mind doing a normal approximation `#Normal aprox
u=300*0.7218128
v=u*(1-0.7218128)
dv=sqrt(v)

pnorm(q=250, mean=u, sd=dv, lower.tail = T, log.p = F)-pnorm(q=150, mean=u, sd=dv, lower.tail = T, log.p = F)` = $0.9999919$ Thanks for your help!!.